# Can't get entity linked to form underlying data entity in form event listener

Tags: forms, symfony, listener, entity-relationship

I have three linked entities, for example: Country, Region and City where 
City is linked with Region and Region is linked with Country (many-to-one).

I want to make a form for City entity. This form should have two selectboxes (Country and Region) and text field for the name of the city.
Selectboxes:

- Region is mapped field (because it is a property of City entity)
- Country is non-mapped field; I add it via form event listener on PRE_SET_DATA

The problem:

When i edit any City - it is successfully linked to Region (correct region is selected in selectbox).
But i can't get Country linked to this Region in event listener. The Region::getCountry() method always return NULL. 
In any other code i can get Country linked to any Region. But not in event listener. I googled all the day and no results.

Here is the code of entities and their relations:

```
class Country
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OQ\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Region", mappedBy="country")
     */
    protected $regions;
}


class Region
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OQ\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Country", inversedBy="regions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="country_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="OQ\ReferenceBundle\Entity\City", mappedBy="region")
     */
    protected $cities;
}

class City
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="OQ\ReferenceBundle\Entity\Region", inversedBy="cities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="region_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $region;
}
```

And there is a code of CityType form:

```
class CityType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {

            if ($event->getData() instanceof City) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                $data = $event->getData();
                $region = $data->getRegion(); // California
                $country = $region->getCountry(); // NULL, but California is related to USA

                $form->add(
                    'country',
                    'translatable_entity',
                    [
                        'mapped' => false,
                        'label' => 'oq.reference.country.entity_label',
                        'class' => 'OQReferenceBundle:Country',
                        'property' => 'name',
                        'required' => true,
                        'empty_value' => 'oq.reference.country.choose',
                        'property_path' => false,
                        'data' => $country
                    ]
                );
            }
        });

        $builder
            ->add(
                'name',
                'text',
                [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label' => 'oq.reference.city.name.label'
                ]
            )->add(
                'region',
                'translatable_entity',
                array(
                    'label' => 'oq.reference.region.entity_label',
                    'class' => 'OQReferenceBundle:Region',
                    'property' => 'name',
                    'required' => true,
                    'empty_value' => 'oq.reference.region.choose'
                )
            );
    }

    ...

}
```

Exactly, this code is trying to get Country from City related Region entity:

```
            $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {

                if ($event->getData() instanceof City) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();
                    $data = $event->getData();
                    $region = $data->getRegion(); // California
                    $country = $region->getCountry(); // NULL, but California is related to USA

                    ...
```

**UPDATE**

I continue solving this problem in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779178/how-symfony-and-doctrine-fetches-associations-deep-associations-and-related-enti), where code is smaller, but question is more global

Comment: Try setting `fetch="EAGER"` in your `Region->country many-to-one` annotation. By the looks of it, you're trying to get the `country` which is associated with a `region`, but that field isn't joined with the sql query because by default `fetch` is set to `LAZY`. This solution isn't good though, because the `country` join will be loaded with every sql query.

Comment: @tftd, ok, i tried. Nothing changed. The country is still NULL.
Such a simple task, such a hard implementation (((

Comment: I continue solving this problem in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779178/how-symfony-and-doctrine-fetches-associations-deep-associations-and-related-enti), where code is smaller, but question is more global

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that strange problem by deleting the cache dir.